# Install older gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, fedora

I have Fedora 31 installed which has gcc 9.3.1 installed into it.

I want to install gcc 4.8.5 on my machine.
Tried compiling the gcc by downloading tar file from gnu website, but facing lot of compilation errors.

Can anone help me with the installation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably the least painful way would be to find a distro that has it (e.g. Ubuntu Xenial) and install that into a VM (virtualbox or kvm) or a chroot (using debootstrap?).

Comment: I think it's fairly unlikely that someone here will want to download gcc 4.8.5 by themselves on Fedora 31, try to compile it, and see what the compilation errors are, and why. Perhaps if you showed some of those errors, someone might be able to tell you what they mean. I have compiled gcc several times in the past, and despite gcc being a rather complicated piece of software, the compilation was mostly a non-event. So, it's likely to be some missing dependencies, or configuration, or something like that, but nobody can give you any pointers without any useful information about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler you are looking for was in a Fedora release many many years ago and will be hard to reasonably get going on a current Fedora Linux system.

However, it *is* the compiler in RHEL 7, and therefore in CentOS. Your best bet is to install one of those operating systems in a virtual machine. (You can get RHEL for individual use through the RH Developer Program.) In Fedora Workstation, the `Boxes` program makes it easy to set up such a VM.

You could also use a docker or podman container, but that will take a little more understanding.